# encoding a POST request

Tags: http

I want to encode a URL such that it sends a POST request to a server. is that possible? and if so, how? I have searched around and mostly found that appending parameters to a url only sends them as parameters for GET request. is there a way to do that for POST request?
basically, i am trying to implement a CSRF (not for malicious but testing purposes) and i want to be able to send a POST request to a server by encoding my url.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "encoding"? Encryption?

Comment: Is this url going to be used in a browser?  Is there code that will be using the url to contact the server?

Answer (score 2):

`GET` and `POST` are [HTTP methods](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html). In [`GET`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.3) the request parameters are taken as query string in the request URL. In [`POST`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.5) the request parameters are taken as query string in the request **body**.

So you need to instruct whatever tool you're using to pass the parameters through the request body instead of the request URL along with a HTTP method of `POST` instead of (usually the default) `GET`.

Either way, the parameters just needs to be URL encoded anyway. There's no difference for POST or GET, unless you're setting the content encoding to [`multipart/form-data`](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2388.html) instead of (usually the default) `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

If you give more details about what programming language and/or library and/or framework you're using, then we may be able to give a more detailed answer how to invoke a HTTP `POST` request.

Answer (score 1):

No.
The method is not part of the Url. You'd have to make the request in such a way that it uses the post method. 
You didn't mention any details, but if it's from inside a document in the browser, you can either use a form:

```
<FORM action="someUrl.htm" method="post">
```

You can make a link that will send the form by javascript:

```
<form action="http://www.example.com/?param=value" method="post" id="someForm">
    <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('someForm').submit();">link</a>
</form>
```

or an XmlHttpRequest with javascript:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", url);
...
```

Comment: sorry if i wasn't clear, ok, so i want to create a link, which when clicked on, sends a POST request to a web server. This POST request is to behave same as the POST request sent by a form in a webpage on that server. And I want this URL for the browser. no code involved, as far as i understand. does that make sense?

Comment: You can't do that with a link. If you want to do a POST, use a form submit button. You can always use CSS to style it so that it looks like a link.

Comment: Added an example of how to trigger the form submission by javascript. It does involve code, but it's all there in the onclick event handler.

Comment: so is there a way to simulate a POST request as a GET request? or will it depend on the context? if a form sends a POST request to a server to post a message on a page. can that be implemented as a GET request?